# What is the spherical law of cosines in high dimensions?

Tags: trigonometry, euclidean-geometry

If I have 3 points on an N-D sphere, does there exist a law of cosines which holds, regardless of the number of dimensions that the sphere occupies?

If so - what is the N-D law of cosines?

EDIT for reference I provide links to wiki pages:

2D Plane Triangle law of cosines:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines

3D Sphere Triangle law of cosines:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_law_of_cosines

4D+ Sphere Triangle law of cosines: WANTED

Comment: As in Euclidean geometry, even in $n$-dimensional space, *three* (non-collinear) points determine *plane*, hence a $2$-dimensional triangle for which the standard Law of Cosines apply. For a proper $n$-dimensional "simplex" (triangle, tetrahedron, etc), you'll want $n+1$ points. Be that as it may ... Years ago, I discovered a Law of Cosines for Spherical (and Hyperbolic) Tetrahedra, relating dihedral angles and face-areas. I am unaware of comparable results in higher dimensions, even for simpler "Pythagorean" configurations involving "right" simplices.

Comment: I find myself confused regarding your comment requiring n+1 points. On a 2D plane, 3 points define a traingle. On a 3D sphere, 3 points still define a triangle (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_law_of_cosines). I naively assume that on a 4D sphere, 3 points still define a triangle.

Comment: I feel perhaps I didn't word the question propertly? feel free to edit and make it more clear now that I have given more context.

Comment: A 3D sphere is a "plane" in spherical (non-Euclidean) geometry. I see now that you aren't thinking in those terms (so you can ignore the stuff about $n+1$ points). In any case, you are correct: $3$ points determine a triangle on an $n$-sphere; but that triangle will still be part of a 3D sub-sphere of the $n$-sphere. (Again, that's just as in any-dimensional space, three points determine a triangle that's part of a planar "sub-space".) So, the trigonometry isn't any more complicated, because a triangle doesn't "notice" the extra dimensions.

Comment: How can the triangle be part of a 3D subsphere and not "notice" extra dimensions? The law of cosines relates SideAngleSide  to a third side of the triangle. The space that the triangle lies upon, determines the way the Angle in the middle (of SideAngleSide) relates to the length of the third triangle side. If that statement were true, wouldn't the the 2D law of cosines be the same as the 3D law of cosines?

Comment: Two points on a line don't "notice" (or care) whether the line itself is in a plane, $3$-space, or some higher-dimensional space. And the somewhat-mundane geometry of those points (basically, the distance between them) remains the same, regardless of the "ambient" surroundings. Likewise with three points on a plane; the measurements of the triangle they form are governed by "plane trigonometry", even if the plane itself happens to be floating around in zillion-dimensional space. [continued]

Comment: I guess our disconnect here stems from the fact that you describe planar triangles as "2D", spherical ones as "3D", and sought-after ones as "4D+". I don't know what a "4D" *triangle* is supposed to be in this progression. The standard way of thinking about spherical triangles is that they, too, are **2**-dimensional; it's just that the 2D surface on which they live happens to be curved in a 3rd dimension. Presumably, you're interested in bending  into a *fourth* dimension, but I don't think "spherical" describes the result. (Think about how you might bend a *line* into the *third* dimension.)

Comment: Using your language - I am interested in triangles where the 2D surface on which they live happens to be curved in a 4th dimension. The way in which they are curved happens to be exactly described by the surface of a 4D - N sphere.

Comment: The problem there is that a 4D sphere's "surface" is *3-dimensional*; just as a 3D sphere's surface is 2-dimensional, and a 2D sphere's "surface" (that is, a circle's circumference) is 1-dimensional, and a 1D sphere's "surface" (that is, a segment's set of endpoints) is 0-dimensional, and in general an $n$-dimensional sphere's surface is $(n-1)$-dimensional. Thus, "The way in which [the triangles] are curved [in a 4th dimension] happens to be exactly described by the surface of a 4D - N sphere" doesn't appear to be a meaningful statement.

Answer (score 3):

Use the vector dot product in the embedding space.  Suppose the two points on the 3-sphere are defined by the coordinates $(\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3)$ and $(\phi_1,\phi_2,\phi_3)$.  Then the coordinates embedded in the 4-d space are

$$\vec{x} = (\cos\theta_1,\sin\theta_1\cos\theta_2,\sin\theta_1\sin\theta_2\cos\theta_3,\sin\theta_1\sin\theta_2\sin\theta_3)$$
$$\vec{y} = (\cos\phi_1,\sin\phi_1\cos\phi_2,\sin\phi_2\sin\phi_2\cos\phi_3,\sin\phi_1\sin\phi_2\sin\phi_3)$$

In a positively curved space we have the relation
$$\cos\psi = \langle x,y\rangle$$
where $\psi$ is the differential angle subtended by the two vectors on the 3-sphere.  This can then be factored to get the final solution

$$\cos\psi = \cos\theta_1\cos\phi_1 + \sin\theta_1\sin\phi_1[\cos\theta_2\cos\phi_2 + \sin\theta_2\sin\phi_2\cos(\theta_3-\phi_3)]$$

You can see how this can be extended to higher dimensions by re-writing the vectors $\vec{x}$ and $\vec{y}$ with the appropriate trig terms.